# some doubts regarding yield()

Tags: java

Some questions regarding the Thread.yield() method. What I have understood is When we call,Thread.Yield(), the currently running thread will go back to the runnable state.So dependes on the thread priority thread scheduler will execute next higher priority thread. Now I have one sample program. Please see below.

```
package thread;

public class YieldTest implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public synchronized  void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+", executing..");
        for(int i = 0 ; i <5;i++){
            if(i==2){               
                Thread.yield();
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": "+i+" yielded()");
                /*try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": "+i+" yielded()");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/

            }else{
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+": "+i);
            }

        }       
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {

    YieldTest test = new YieldTest();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(test);
        t1.setName("A");
        t1.setPriority(9);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(test);
        t2.setName("B");
        Thread t3 = new Thread(test);
        t3.setName("C");

        t2.setPriority(6);
        t2.setPriority(4);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

    }


}
```

Here I am getting the output always in the following way,

```
A, executing..
A: 0
A: 1
A: 2 yielded()
A: 3
A: 4
C, executing..
C: 0
C: 1
C: 2 yielded()
C: 3
C: 4
B, executing..
B: 0
B: 1
B: 2 yielded()
B: 3
B: 4
```

Now the question is yield() method should go back to the runable state and other thread should execute. so the output should be something like the following way

A, executing..
    A: 0
    A: 1
    A: 2 yielded()

C, executing..
    C: 0
    C: 1
    C: 2 yielded()

```
A: 3
A: 4
```

B, executing..
    B: 0
    B: 1
    B: 2 yielded()

```
C: 3
C: 4

B: 3
B: 4
```

Also, what about the thread priority. Is it not guaranteed why do we need thread priority?Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve? Calling `yield()` is probably not the best solution.

Comment: For more on `yield()`, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156985/how-does-method-yield-work).

Comment: In this particular scenario, I would not be surprised if thread A completed before B even had time to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your run methods are synchronized on the same object (test). So yielding doesnt acheive anything, since until the first thread's run method exits, no others can enter their run() methods.

Basically thread 1 starts, and enters the run() method. This is synchronized on 'this'. After outputting 2 numbers, it yields. But threads 2 and 3 are both waiting to enter the run method, since they cannot obtain a monitor on test. So yield doesnt do anything. The same issue then happens once thread one has finished.

Comment: Ok thanks good information. If it is not sychronized, then we cannot achieve the property result like oe thread after one thread in that way..

Answer (score 2):

So yield was more useful when Java was using Green Threading.  Now while it will notify the OS a thread could be placed into a waiting state (NOT runnable).  But, it's really up to the OS and the JVM as to whether the thread will actually yield to allow another thread to run.  And which thread that is, is out of your control.

But, ultimately I've never used yield for anything ever.  What in the world are you trying to use it for?

Comment: so we should never use or avoid using Thread.yield() as it is purely dependent on platform and JVM. Is that correct? Instead of Yield() better to use wait(). am I right?

Comment: The issue isn't portability as much as control.  You don't have enough control using yield to do any form of synchronization between threads.  I can't think of a problem that yield would solve.  The problem with your question is that you asked about yield, but didn't really say why you thought you needed yield.  Using wait/notify/notifyAll and synchronize in order to have full control, but again there are other ways that usually are easier.  It just comes down to what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, thread priority is not guaranteed. It's just a suggestion to the JVM, and the JVM can look at other factors when deciding which thread to actually run. Technically, a JVM can even choose at random, if it so desires, and still conform to [the JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Threads.doc.html).

Answer (score 0):

Thread.yield: It's a static method which is essentially used to notify the system that the current thread is willing to "give up the CPU" for a while.

The thread scheduler can  select a different thread to run instead of the current one.

However, the details of how yielding is implemented by the thread scheduler differ from platform to platform. In general, you shouldn't rely on it behaving in a particular way. Things that differ include:

```
1.when, after yielding, the thread will get an opportunity to run again;
2.whether or not the thread forgoes its remaining quantum.
```

Thread Priority:

At any given time, the highest priority thread is running. However, this is not guaranteed. The thread scheduler may choose to run a lower priority thread to avoid starvation. For this reason, use priority only to affect scheduling policy for efficiency purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.yield() like thread priorities are just suggestions to the OS.  There is no guarantee that yield() will stop the current thread. It doesn't guarantee that a higher priority thread will run at that point as the OS can stop your thread anywhere. There is no guarantee that a higher priority thread will have higher priority or this will make any difference if it does.

IMHO It is not a good idea to try to write your own scheduler in Java.  It is highly unlikely to help or behave in the manner you might think.